# Laravel does not include file

Tags: php, laravel

Hello i am new to laravel framework and i am learning this framework and i am using blade templating engine for the separating the code.i have creating 2 file like sidebar.blade.php and footer.blade.php and i have to call both the file in my index .php but it's not working. my file is in my-project/layout/sidebar.blade.php folder

here is my code: 
index.php

```
<body class="nav-md">
    <div class="container body">
      <div class="main_container">
        @include('layouts.sidebar')
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

sidebar.blade.php

```
  <!-- footer content -->
    <footer>
      <div class="pull-right">
        Gentelella - Bootstrap Admin Template by <a href="https://colorlib.com">Colorlib</a>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </footer>
    <!-- /footer content -->
```

file structure :
[image]

[image]

result :

[image]

Comment: Could you please share the folder structure

Comment: "but it's not working". Could you please elaborate what you expect and what you have?

Comment: its suppose to render the code for sidemenu but it is not being working like that way.instead its shows me  @include('includes.sidebar') on the browser

Comment: @Mahi Parmar change it to @include('layouts.sidebar');

Comment: your master blade should be index.blade.php and use `@include('layout.sidebar')`

Comment: i also did @sandy but not working

Comment: @Mahi Parmar your folder structure is not proper just cut your layout folder and paste it in resources/views dicrectory.

Comment: all blade files must inside resources/views

Comment: yes i did this also @sandy

Comment: @MahiParmar upload the ss of layout floder. I think there is some problem in your directory structure.

Comment: @MahiParmar i suggest you to read this https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/structure.It will really help you.

Comment: this link is broker @sandy

Comment: @MahiParmar https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/structure

Comment: i have also add answer just read it may be it will also help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resources directory contains your views as well as your raw, un-compiled assets such as LESS, SASS, or JavaScript. This directory also houses all of your language files.

first you need to save all your view file with the extension of .blade.php Ex. 'yourfile-name.blade.php' and it must be in resources/views directory. If you want to add any new directory in that then you can add but when you include any file you have to specify the name of that directory like @include('your-folderName.bladeFileName');

Comment: did this way but not getting the exact result

Comment: what is the problem? and tell me what you did if possible then please upload bit of code you have tried.

Comment: as i updated my directory structure which everybody had suggested me. an i had also share piece of code what i m trying to do.As  you can see in my result screen shot raw code is being displayed upon the sidenav

Comment: my problem remains same

Comment: can you please explain what is the problem? @MahiParmar

Comment: i wanted to display the sidenav menu as displyed in the image . for that purpose i have created .blade file and put that file in the  resources/view/layouts folder and then i had include that file where i wanted to display the sidenav menu. but my problem is it is not beiing included that file and just raw code is being displayd as u can see in the screen shot at the extreme left corner.what should i do now?

Comment: ok @MahiParmar i got your point. Now tell me have you split your main index.blade file in different blade file like header,footer,sidebar,etc?

Comment: is there any way to see your code directly and can i change it directly? like to connect your pc with my pc or else so that i can have batter idea and i can help you out.

Comment: actually i thnik i know where the problem is but i cant explain you properly so if possible then connect through any other medium.

Comment: let you do one thing send me the index.blade.php file i will split it and solve your problem and i will send you.

Comment: how could i share file with you?please share email id

Comment: please share email id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174762/discussion-between-sandy-and-mahi-parmar).

Answer (score 3):

For a default Laravel installation the `@include()` in `@include('includes.sidebar')` call will look for the file from `project_root\resources\views` directory. So just organize your view files that way and `@include()` it.

Another thing is, `@include()` is a `blade` directive. To use this you need a blade file first. So, I am guessing your `index.php` file should be `index.blade.php`

Comment: hey i did the same as u instructed but still i m having same issue

Comment: What did you exactly do? And how are you loading your view file? Share some code in details, please.

Answer (score 1):

project_folder/resources/views/index.blade.php

```
<body class="nav-md">
    <div class="container body">
    <div class="main_container">
        @include('layout.sidebar')
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

project_folder/resources/views/layout/sidebar.blade.php

```
<hr>
<p>This is sidebar</p>
<hr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body class="nav-md">
<div class="container body">
  <div class="main_container">
    @include('layout.sidebar')
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please share structure of views folder. If you specify includes.sidebar then your sidebar.blade.php must in view/includes folder.